# Linux SVN not communicating with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I have SVN setup on the server, but when I try to do a checkout remotely via SSH it throws a 200 OK response, rather than processing my checkout.  I think I've missed a step with the SVN and how it communicates with apache.... any thoughts?

Comment: 200 OK? Isn't that an HTTP response?

Comment: If you've setup your svn repositories to be served by apache (via mod_dav_svn) then you should be using an http/https url for your repository, not ssh+svn most likely.  Otherwise need more context for a real answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and bookmark [the official SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/). It's got many handy references, [like this table.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) Let me call your attention to this table There are three common ways to connect to SVN:

1. **SVN procotol**. SVN server listening on port 3690. URIs start with `svn://`
2. **SVN+SSH**. SSH listening (port 22 by default) with a local SVN daemon launched for the duration of the transaction. URIs start with `svn+ssh://`
3. **HTTP**. Apache listening on port 80/443 for HTTP requests, and directing them to mod_dav_svn. This is what you claim to be using. URIs start with `https://`

If you have only set up Apache then you need to use something like `https://example.com/repo/path`

Comment: https uses port 443, not 447.